# Configuring an IP address to a Cloud Run

Tags: python, sql-server, google-cloud-platform, network-programming, cloud

So I am using a python script to connect to the azure sql server using an odbc connector through the pyodbc package. Once it is connected, i run a query and import the data into a dataframe and then load it into bigquery. The sql server has a network policy so I needed to whitelist my ip address to access the sql server through python. Once the ip address was whitelisted, the python script runs perfect on my local enviornment. I dockerized the script and ran it through docker locally and it worked perfect too. Now I need this script to run on a google cloud platform environment and my first thought was to use cloud run to run the container. Here is what the script looks like:

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from google.cloud import bigquery
import datetime as dt
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)

from requests import get


cnxn_str = (
            "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};"
            "SERVER=emp-something.database.windows.net;"
            "DATABASE=xxxx;"
            "UID=xxxx;"
            "PWD=xxxx;"
            "Encrypt=no;"
            "TrustServerCertificate=yes")
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxn_str)
bigquery_client =  bigquery.Client(project='personal')
dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset('Landing')


Schema = 'employees'
Table = 'users'
query = """select * from """ + Schema + "." + Table + ";"


df = pd.read_sql(query,cnxn)


df.insert(0, 'TransferID', range(202301, 202301 + len(df)))
df['updated_at'] = dt.datetime.now()
df['CurrentVersion'] = 0
df.head()


table = 'x.Landing.emp'+'_'+Table
job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table)
```

Now the problem is how can I run this script on cloud run? I need some sort of outbound IP address to access the azure sql server from cloud run.

So what I tried to do is create a cloud router with a static ip address and add it into a VPC service and then I drove the traffic of cloud run to that VPC Service. Then I whitelisted the static ip address on the sql server.
I was using this [resource](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip) as a guide.

But for some reason I can't get the sql server to be able to connect to the cloud run app. I am getting two different errors when I run the cloud run app

First error is:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/full_load.py", line 18, in <module>
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxn_str)
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

This is when I configure 'Traffic Routing' on Cloud Run to 'Route all traffic to the VPC'

and second error is:

```
 ('42000', "[42000] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open server 'emp.something' requested by the login. Client with IP address 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to access the server. To enable access, use the Azure Management Portal or run sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule for this IP address or address range. It may take up to five minutes for this change to take effect. (40615) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

This is when I configure 'Traffic Routing' on Cloud Run to Route only requests to private IPs to the VPC. Here the IP Address that it showed here 'Client with IP address 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx'' wasn't the one that I configured and whitelisted and is completely different so maybe I am doing something completely wrong.

Can anyone tell me the best way to resolve this or any other way I can work on this.

Thank you so much!

Comment: The issue is that you're routing only private IPs but you should route all the traffic.

Comment: @Puteri when I route all the traffic I get this error with the cloud run:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/full_load.py", line 18, in <module>
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxn_str)
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') `
I have whitelisted the static IP address, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is the IP of the DB in Azure public or private?

Comment: Aside... `"Encrypt=no;"` is something (barely) acceptable to do on LANs for development purposes, but you certainly shouldn't be doing this in or between cloud hosting environments.

Comment: And a script can be run on Cloud Run Job, not on cloud run (which requires an HTTP server)